# Setting app icon as progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-studio, progress-bar

On my android application on the splash screen I need to set my app icon as rotating progress bar how can I implement that.

Can anyone help me with the code ?
For example [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8ilgjn6fzxntv2/10529664_833402360077760_131396055_n.jpg?dl=0]

The image is the screenshot of an app which uses the encircled image as progress bar . I need to implement exactly this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for rotation.

```
ImageView rotate_image =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image);
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(30, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotate.setDuration(2500);
rotate_image.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks